# Refreshing a Fragment after the tab has been selected

Tags: android, android-fragments

When my fragment is built, I build the View from information in my local Database. Other tabs can modify this information, and when the user selects the tab, I would like the new information to be reflected.

```
public class RunningTotal extends SherlockFragment {
    public static final String TAG = "Running Total";
    private LinearLayout lv;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater li, ViewGroup vg,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        SalesDataSource sds = BarcodeSaleTracker.SDS;

        ArrayList<Item> items = sds.getAllItems();
        String[] totals = sds.getPersonValues();
        int totalsPosition = 0;
        Log.v(TAG, "Items Length: " + items.size());

        lv = new LinearLayout(this.getActivity());

        String lastPerson = "";

        if (items.size() > 0) {
            for (Item i : items) {
                if (lastPerson.equalsIgnoreCase(i.getPerson()) == false) {
                    lastPerson = i.getPerson();
                    TextView tv = (TextView) li.inflate(R.layout.list_title,
                            lv, false);
                    tv.setText(totals[totalsPosition]);
                    totalsPosition++;
                    lv.addView(tv);
                }

                TextView listItem = (TextView) li.inflate(R.layout.list_item,
                        lv, false);
                listItem.setText(i.toString());
                lv.addView(listItem);
            }
        } else {
            TextView noItems = (TextView) li.inflate(R.layout.list_title, lv,
                    false);
            noItems.setText(R.string.no_items);
            lv.addView(noItems);
        }

        return lv;
    }
}
```

It's a tabbed format, nearly identical to the Sherlock example:

```
public class BarcodeSaleTracker extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
    TabHost mTabHost;
    ViewPager mViewPager;
    TabsAdapter mTabsAdapter;

    public static SalesDataSource SDS;

    public BarcodeSaleTracker() {

    }

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTheme(R.style.Sherlock___Theme);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SDS = new SalesDataSource(this);
        SDS.open();

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            setContentView(R.layout.fragment_tabs_pager);

            mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
            mTabHost.setup();

            mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

            mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, mTabHost, mViewPager);

            mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("current_sale")
                    .setIndicator("Current Sale"), Current_Sale.class, null);
            mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("running_total")
                    .setIndicator("Running Total"), RunningTotal.class, null);
            mTabsAdapter.addTab(
                    mTabHost.newTabSpec("stats").setIndicator("Stats"),
                    CountingFragment.class, null);
        } else {
            mTabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(savedInstanceState.getString("tab"));
        }
    }
```

I just don't know *how* to communicate to RunningTotal that it needs to update itself.

**EDIT** Added the source of all the data I ask from the database

```
public class SalesDataSource {
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
    private String[] allColumns = { DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_ID,
            DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_PERSON, DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_COST,
            DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_ITEM };

    public SalesDataSource(Context context) {
        dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    public void open() throws SQLException {
        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void close() {
        dbHelper.close();
    }

    /**
     * Creates an entry in the Database. Both a person and a cost are required.
     * Item is not required. If one is not needed, simply pass null.
     * 
     * @param person
     *            Who this sale belongs to.
     * @param cost
     *            The amount (in pennies) that the sale was.
     * @param item
     *            An optional description of the sold item
     * @return The newly created Item.
     */
    public Item addItem(String person, int cost, String item) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_PERSON, person);
        values.put(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_COST, cost);
        values.put(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_ITEM, item);

        long insertId = database.insert(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_SALES, null,
                values);

        Cursor cursor = database.query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_SALES, allColumns,
                DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = " + insertId, null, null, null,
                null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        Item rv = cursorToItem(cursor);
        cursor.close();

        return rv;
    }

    public void addItems(List<Item> items) {
        for (Item i : items) {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

            values.put(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_PERSON, i.getPerson());
            values.put(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_COST, i.getAmount());
            values.put(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_ITEM, i.getItem());

            database.insert(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_SALES, null, values);
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Item> getAllItems() {
        ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();

        Cursor cursor = database.query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_SALES, allColumns,
                null, null, null, null, DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_PERSON);

        cursor.moveToFirst();

        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            Item item = cursorToItem(cursor);
            items.add(item);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }

        cursor.close();

        return items;
    }

    public String[] getPersonValues() {
        Cursor cursor = database.query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_SALES,
                new String[] { "SUM(" + DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_COST + ") AS " + DatabaseHelper.PERSON_SUM,
                        DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_PERSON }, null, null,
                DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_PERSON, null, null);
        String[] rv = new String[cursor.getCount()];

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int pos = 0;
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            String person = cursor.getString(1);
            String money = Item.format(cursor.getInt(0));
            rv[pos++] = person + ": " + money;
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }

        cursor.close();

        return rv;
    }

    public Item getMaxSale() {
        Cursor cursor = database.query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_SALES,
                new String[] { "MAX(" + DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_COST + ") AS " + DatabaseHelper.MAX_SALE,
                        DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_PERSON }, null, null, null, null,
                null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();


        Item rv = cursorToItem(cursor);
        cursor.close();
        return rv;

    }

    public Item getMinSale() {
        Cursor cursor = database.query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_SALES,
                new String[] { "MIN(" + DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_COST + ") AS " + DatabaseHelper.MIN_SALE,
                        DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_PERSON }, null, null, null, null,
                null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();

        Item rv = cursorToItem(cursor);
        cursor.close();
        return rv;

    }

    private Item cursorToItem(Cursor cursor) {
        Item item = new Item();

        item.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
        item.setPerson(cursor.getString(1));
        item.setAmount(cursor.getInt(2));
        item.setItem(cursor.getString(3));

        return item;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a listfragment and loadermanager to manage the cursor object so that the list is automatically updated whenever the underlying data changes?

Comment: The problem is that it's more than just a simple Curosr object. I'm using more than one cursor object, and transforming some of the data. I've updated my original post with my SalesDataSource.

Comment: Then you can use ContentObservers